# How to convert MKV movies 5.1 audio tracks to 2.0 (Stereo) but keep the original ones

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mkv

To solve a problem I had where 5.1 movies had really quite dialogues, I'm using FFMPEG to convert every audio track of my MKV movies to an 2.0 track with audio normalization, leaving video and subtitles intact.

Here's what the command looks like:

```
for /r %%i in (*.mkv) do (
    @ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -v 32 -stats -y -i "%%i" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s? -c:s copy -c:v copy -acodec ac3 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 640k -af %aproc2%  -f matroska "%%~ni [Stereo].mkv"
)
```

What I'd like to do now is having these converted audio track *added* to the MKV among the 5.1 tracks, and not replacing the originals, which I may want in future.

I'm not really an expert of FFMPEG, so I'm looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for /r %%i in (*.mkv) do (
    @ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -v 32 -stats -y -i "%%i" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:s? -c:s copy -c:v copy -c:a:0 ac3 -ac:a:0 2 -ar:a:0 48000 -ab:a:0 640k -filter:a:0 %aproc2% -c:a:1 copy -f matroska "%%~ni [Stereo].mkv"
)
```

The audio is mapped twice. All audio options have a output stream specifier attached so they only apply to the first audio output and the codec for the 2nd audio output is set to copy.

---

For inputs with multiple tracks, you'll need multiple commands

```
for /r %%i in (*.mkv) do (
    @ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -v 32 -stats -y -i "%%i" -map 0:a -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 640k -filter:a %aproc2% -f matroska "%%~dpni [Stereo].mka"
    @ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -v 32 -stats -y -i "%%i" -i "%%~dpni [Stereo].mka" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -map 0:s? -c copy -f matroska "%%~ni [Stereo].mkv"
)
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! That's exactly what I was looking for. Just an extra question: do you know how to rename each audio track detailing the channels and the language, in an automated way? Like "5.1 English", "2.0 English", "5.1 Italian", "2.0 Italian". That would be so helpful in various scenarios.

Comment: Mhm, after another test, I noticed the command does not work properly. Out of two 5.1 tracks, it creates another two, but just one of them is Stereo, the other is duplicated 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the new command, the output has indeed the tracks added, but they are empty (no sound, and the total file size is almost the same of the original with half the tracks).

Comment: Full bat code: https://pastebin.com/qC9PKJRB Full output log: https://pastebin.com/CaqKB9bs . I really appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Comment: In the second command, I see `[matroska,webm @ 0000024ae5e172c0] Read error`. Try with another file. Or, save the stereo audio to MP4s and remux those.

Comment: @aur0n Please reword your comment. There's no need to use swear words. Thank you.

Comment: @chade_ Sorry, you're right. Somehow I can't seem to be able to edit the comment, the pencil icon does nothing.

Comment: @aur0n You can only edit a comment for a short period of time (some few minutes), but you can delete and recreate the comment.

Comment: @Mulvya after some deeper analysis, I found out that VLC does report 4 tracks. MPC-HC instead has 6 audio tracks selection, but in media properties I only see 4. I guess it's something, but I'm curious to know why it lists 6 (four stereo, two 5.1)

Comment: Well, the new log shows expected outcome. Can't comment on MPC's behaviour.